# Is there a term do refer to a "set of sets" in math, to distinguish set of regular math objet?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

In mathematics, a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is a well-defined collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right.

for example

```
A = {2, 1, 3}
B = {blue, white, red}
C = {3, 5, 6}
D = {A, C}
```

all the above are sets, A, B, C are regular sets, and D is a set of set. Is there a term do refer to this type of set(D), to distinguish set of other sets (like A, B, C)?

"regular" math objet may not be a precise term, "regular" used here to distinguish a set to from a simple/regular one, such as real numbers that could be an operand of an elementary function.

Comment: It's called a set of sets.  What makes you think a set isn't "a regular math object"?

Comment: In what situation do you see a *need* to make such a distinction? In a way "all" mathematical objects "are" sets of sets - at least if their existence can be justified via ZFC set theory.

Comment: In fact, in formal set theory, there is nothing but sets - everything other than the empty set is a set of sets.

Comment: @saulspatz "regular" math objet may not be a precise term, "regular" used here to distinguish a set to from a simple/regular one, such as real numbers that could be an operand of an elementary function. please correct me if there is a more appropriate term could be used.

Comment: I really don't know how to answer this.  In NBG set theory, which is what I learned, everything is a set, so all the simple objects you describe are sets.  I know there are set theories that allow non-sets ("atoms") but I don't know anything about them, and anyway, I doubt that something as complicated as a real number would be an atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "*family*" is used for sets of sets. This usage is most common when all the elements of the sets in the family are of the same kind (So in your examples $D = \{A,C\} = \{\{1,2,3\},\{3,5,6\}\}$ is a more typical example than say $\{A,B\} = \{\{1,2,3\},\{\mathrm{blue},\mathrm{white},\mathrm{red}\}\}$). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets):

> In set theory and related branches of mathematics, a collection F of subsets of a given set S is called a family of subsets of S, or a family of sets over S. More generally, a collection of any sets whatsoever is called a family of sets.

Answer (score 1):

I was trained to refer to a set of sets as a **collection**, I suppose so that it would be relatively clear when I was referring to the encompassing set and when I was referring to the sets which were members.  A quick trip to Google shows me that this verbiage is somewhere between standard and "not unheard of", so you're welcome to join if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. apply this verbiage to my case, D is a collection, in which A, C are its members, A is member set, right?

Comment: @JJJohn Yes.  Specifically, A is a member set of C.