Number of subsets of a power set with a specific maximality property
Let $P(n) := \mathscr P(\{0,\ldots, n-1\})$ .
I am interested in subsets $F \subseteq P(n)$ of the power set with a special property, that no two sets are proper subsets of each other.
(According to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3457676/290307 , F like Family, to avoid confusion about sets of sets.)
Minor question: is there a name for families with this property?
Major question: for given $n$, how many families are there with this property?
Obviously, every family where each element has the same number $k$ of elements has this property, and every sub-family with fewer elements inherits that property.
But it sucks my brains out to get any further.

This is called an antichain in general, and in this particular case is called a Sperner family. They are counted by the Dedekind numbers $M(n)$, which are A000372 on the OEIS. Apparently exact values are only known up to $n = 9$ (which was computed in 2023!) so this seems like a difficult problem.
By Dilworth's theorem the largest Sperner family is the family of subsets of size $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$. Every subfamily of this family remains a Sperner family, which gives a lower bound
$$M(n) \ge 2^{ {n \choose \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} }.$$
(For odd $n$ this can be improved by a factor of $2$ since we can also count families of subsets of size $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1$.) There is a matching upper bound on $\log_2 M(n)$ given on Wikipedia so this gives a rough idea of how fast $M(n)$ grows.
